# Format a decorator in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-decorators

RANT - Why do people say 'a decorator is a function that returns another function'? That definition makes no sense, because if that's all a decorator is, why wouldn't you just use the second function and not fool with the first at all? - END RANT

Fortunately, I found a much more sensible definition here:
http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/

Unfortunately, I still don't understand the examples, like this one:

```
def get_text(name):
   return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
   return func_wrapper

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)

print my_get_text("John")

#Outputs "<p>lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>"
```

Note, the post is more than two years old and the authors have not responded to any of the comments.

Here's my question: Why doesn't it output

```
"<p>John</p>"
```

or an error? How does the whole string get inside the p tags instead of just the name?

Comment: You are confusing a function and what a function returns.  A decorator can return a different function depending on what argument (another function) it is given.  It does not call the function that it returns, but usually the function that it returns, *when called*, calls the function that is originally given to the decorator.

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the rest of that article... it explains in grueling detail what exactly is happening, what the goals are, and how to achieve that goal using the facilities provided by python...

Comment: @JeffMercado: Maybe that's why he mentioned that article as having a "much more sensible definition"...  He didn't tell us which article doesn't make sense to him.

Comment: ok, Jeff and zondo, let me try this again. Maybe my issue is more with format() than it is with decorators. In the def tag example, the return is <{0}>}{1}</{0}>. This I can follow because the {0} = p and the {1} is the string. But since the string variable is **just** {1}, why isn't that just **John**? How is it that the Hello gets inserted, and does not overwrite John?

Comment: It sounds like the deeper source of your confusion is closures. Do you know what a closure is and how they work? If not, go read about those.

Comment: The rest of the article I cited did **not** answer the question I posed here. But JeffMercado gets a +1 and I get -2? That means neither Jeff nor his supporters read or understood _my question_. They also didn't respond when I tried to clarify. How is that fair and reasonable? At least Pythonista took the time to understand what was being asked and give an explanatory answer.

Comment: Probably because you ranted about things you don't understand. That's rarely a good idea.

Comment: But it's a good idea to insult people who come to you for help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I just realized you had an article linked that literally explains what decorators are step by step... but this is already typed up so...

There's a feature called closures / function closures in Python.

It's been awhile since I tried to explain / understand what happens at a lower level with closures / decorators so this might actually be wrong.

The function func_wrapper is being redefined each time `p_decorate` is called, and func_wrapper will remember what the ***enclosing*** namespace looks like at the time of definition.

**What does this mean:**

As an example, say you had some outer variable nested within `p_decorate` you would expect this to throw an error since it no longer exists (it's non-local to func_wrapper) when `func_wrapper` is called and tries to use this variable, but it won't since the enclosing namespace is "remembered"

In python 3 it's `__closure__` and in python 2 it's `func_closure` for below.

```
def get_text(name):
    return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
    def func_wrapper(name):
        return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name)) #Cached result
    print(func_wrapper.func_closure)
    return func_wrapper

my_get_text1 = p_decorate(get_text)
my_get_text2 = p_decorate(get_text2)
```

func_closure stuff:

```
my_get_text1 >>> (<cell at 0x*: function object at 0x*>,)
my_get_text2 >>> (<cell at 0x(different address): function object at (diff address)>,)
```

We aren’t passing the different functions to the `func_wrapper` function but are building custom versions of the `func_wrapper` function that "remembers" what function it should call by using `func`.

If you passed in the same function twice for `my_get_text1` and `my_get_text2` you'd have the exact same thing for the `func_wrapper.func_closure` bit, memory address and everything for `function object at *`, since it's the same function. (Minus when you actually call it with a potentially different argument.)

**decorators**:

A decorator is as you noted simply a callable that takes a function as an argument and returns a replacement function. In your code this would be `p_decorator` and `func_wrapper` respectively.

If you wanted to think of this in OOP way... You can think of `p_decorate` as a constructor for the function `func_wrapper` with func acting like a private member variable / attribute since you have more or less essentially built a function with a hard-coded argument `func`.

**Why it returns what it does:**

Hopefully the above is all correct + makes sense... Then, it returns the value you see because you have passed the `get_text` function which is "remembered" and since `func_wrapper` is returned... You are calling `func_wrapper(arg)` with an argument of `John` now inside of this... `func_wrapper` returns the following:

```
"<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))"
```

With `func` being `get_text`. So, `get_text` is called which returns...

```
"lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)
```

And then this is formatted in between the opening and closing `p` tag and then returned.

You can have multiple layers of nested functions, and as with pretty much anything in python it's turtles all the way down.

**Why even bother using decorators?**

In this example I think you're right that I'd just use the second function since this is a pretty useless example.

But, consider something more concrete. I'll use a common django decorator as an example off the top of my head. Even if you're not familiar with Django this should still make sense.

In django you have functions / views which render webpages and sometimes you may want to require a user to be logged in to view a page.

Now, what if you had to write **custom logic for *every single function* you want this on**.

That would be terrible. Instead there's a nifty decorator named `@login_required` that you simply put at the top of the function you want this functionality for and you just saved a ton of time / duplicated code, because this decorator wraps this custom logic around the function you've applied it to.

Decorators are mainly useful when you want to extend / customize functions without having to recode everything.

Going even further than functions.... What if you wanted to apply this to methods of a `class`. Maybe all of them or one's meeting certain criteria? It would get a bit tedious and potentially annoying to have to do that for every single method. Instead of wrapping every single method with an `@decorator_name` you could write a decorator to wrap the class and apply this to every function auto-magically for you.

Comment: I need to see if I can put this in my own English to see if I am understanding you:

Return the argument, (name), wrapped in p tags, but do so in the format of the original function, get_text, so the result in full becomes "lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet" 

So the variable {0} is neither being replaced nor overwritten, but 'formatted' to comply with the original function. Does that make sense? Is that a correct plain English explanation?

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying and if so then yes. The `{0}` in get_text isn't affected by the `{0}` in `func_wrapper`. When `func_wrapper` calls `func(name)` it returns the string `"lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet"` which was created by formatting `name` into the `{0}` in `get_text` and then this string is formatted into the `{0}` in `func_wrapper`. So, you have `<p>(string returned by get_text)</p>` returned by `func_wrapper`